# Random rounding to integer in Python

Tags: python, integer, probability, rounding

I am looking for a way to round a floating point number up or down to the next integer based on a probability derived from the numbers after the decimal point. For example the floating number 6.1 can be rounded to 6 and to 7. The probability for beeing rounded to 7 is 0.1 and the probability to be rounded to 6 is 1-0.1. So if I run this rounding experiment infinite times, the average of all integer results should be 6.1 again. I don't know if there is a name for such a procedure and if there is already and implemented function in Python.
Of course it'd be very nice if it is possible to round also to e.g. 2 decimal places the same way.

Does that make sense? Any ideas?

Comment: I cannot see any sense in this endeavor (-: - but this is possible; get your significant digits as an integer and multiply with `numpy.random.rand()` for your rounding decision I guess.

Comment: There is a name for such procedure which is: Stochastic rounding, see : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Stochastic_rounding

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The probability you're looking for is `x-int(x)`.

To sample with this probability, do `random.random() < x-int(x)`

```
import random
import math
import numpy as np

def prob_round(x):
    sign = np.sign(x)
    x = abs(x)
    is_up = random.random() < x-int(x)
    round_func = math.ceil if is_up else math.floor
    return sign * round_func(x)

x = 6.1
sum( prob_round(x) for i in range(100) ) / 100.
=> 6.12
```

EDIT: adding an optional `prec` argument:

```
def prob_round(x, prec = 0):
    fixup = np.sign(x) * 10**prec
    x *= fixup
    is_up = random.random() < x-int(x)
    round_func = math.ceil if is_up else math.floor
    return round_func(x) / fixup

x = 8.33333333
[ prob_round(x, prec = 2) for i in range(10) ]
=> [8.3399999999999999,
 8.3300000000000001,
 8.3399999999999999,
 8.3300000000000001,
 8.3300000000000001,
 8.3300000000000001,
 8.3300000000000001,
 8.3300000000000001,
 8.3399999999999999,
 8.3399999999999999]
```

Comment: Can this be implemented without branching?

Comment: @étale-cohomology, sure. You can do: `math.floor(x) + (random.random() < x-int(x))`. Which version is more readable is arguable.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a nice one-liner for this.  By using the floor function, it will only be rounded up if the random number between 0 and 1 is enough to bring it up to the next highest integer.  This method also works with positive and negative numbers equally well.

```
def probabilistic_round(x):
    return int(math.floor(x + random.random()))
```

Consider the case of a negative input `x = -2.25`.  75% of the time the random number will be greater than or equal to 0.25 in which case the floor function will result in -2 being the answer.  The other 25% of time the number will get rounded down to -3.

To round to different decimal places it can be modified as follows:

```
def probabilistic_round(x, decimal_places=0):
    factor = 10.0**decimal_places
    return int(math.floor(x*factor + random.random()))/factor
```

Answer (score 6):

The most succinct way to do this for non-negative x is:

```
int(x + random.random())
```

If for example `x == 6.1`, then there's a 10% chance that `random.random()` will be large enough to make `x + random.random() >= 7`.

Note that if `x == 6`, then this expression is guaranteed to return `6`, because `random.random()` is always in the range [0, 1).

Update: This method only works for non-negative inputs. For a solution that works for negative numbers, see Chris Locke's answer.

Answer (score 2):

For rounding positive values to integers, you can do this very concisely:

```
x = int(x) + (random.random() < x - int(x))
```

This works because Python's `bool` type is a subclass of `int`. The value `True` is equal to 1 and `False` is equal to 0.

Answer (score 1):

I also came up with a solution based on the binomial function of random and the code already provided by shx2:

```
def prob_round(x, prec = 0):
    fixup = np.sign(x) * 10**prec
    x *= fixup 
    round_func = int(x) + np.random.binomial(1,x-int(x))
    return round_func/fixup
```

Answer (score -2):

Here's an easy way:

```
x = round(random.random()*100)
```

The `*100` bit means 1 to 100.
If `*200`, it means 1 to 200.